# Executar Cronjob Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, cron

Como executar um método de uma classe no Codeigniter via CronJob?

Ex: principal.php acessado em http://www.meusite.com.br/principal/listaCron

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Principal extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    //Load Dependencies     
  }

  public function listaCron()
  {     
     file_put_contents("teste.txt", "Crontab executado em: ".date(‘d/m/Y H:i’));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue link do manual para isso http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html.

no meu local eu deixei para rodar assim:

```
0 1 * * * php /var/www/meusite/index.php principal listaCron
```

mas no servidor tive que rodar pelo curl

```
0 1 * * * /usr/bin/curl -L --silent http://www.meusite.com.br/index.php/principal/listaCron
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso seu servidor tenha suporte para **curl**, você pode adicionar isto na linha de comando do Crontab:

curl http://www.meusite.com.br/principal/listaCron